# `UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(:)` method not working on iOS 11.4 (iPad Devices Only)?

Tags: ios, swift, ipad

Why `UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(:)` method not working on iOS 11.4 - iPad Devices? although it's working fine on iOS 11 & 12.0 [iPhone devices]!

Note:

- Code written in Swift 4.2
- Passed url is valid
- I use `https`

Comment: They work just fine on other simulators and devices?

Comment: App rejected by Apple and fixed the problem by removing this method !

Comment: `UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(:)` works fine on iOS 11 & 12.0 [iPhone devices]

Answer (score 1):

Ok, Bro, I had the same problem with facebook open share link and I solve the problem when I change the **shareDialog.mode** to **.automatic**

So you can try this way and tell me if it works?

```
let url = URL(string: "www.google.com")
let content = LinkShareContent(url: url, quote: "Google")
let shareDialog = ShareDialog(content: content)
shareDialog.mode = .automatic
shareDialog.presentingViewController = self
shareDialog.failsOnInvalidData = true
shareDialog.completion = { result in

}

do {
        try shareDialog.show()
} catch {
        print("Error")
}
```

as our discussion, you need to open a web view in your app

so you can add this

```
import UIKit

class WebVC: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

var url = ""
var firstLoad = true

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.setup()
}

func setup() {

    self.webView.backgroundColor = Color.white.value
    self.webView.delegate = self

    var urlRequest =  URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
    urlRequest.cachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringCacheData
    self.webView.loadRequest(urlRequest)
}
}
```

and in your controller, you can use

```
func openWebView() {

   let webVC = WebVC()
   webVC.url = "www.google.com"
   webVC.title = "Google"
   self.navigationController?.pushViewController(webVC, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't use `UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(:) method` in sharing! I use it to open an url in a webview

Comment: Ok, Bro, I can share with you a WebVC it is work with me 
You can replace it with the other

Comment: The problem in url validation phase not in opening the url in a webview